# Mix c# and vb.net webforms in single project

Tags: asp.net

I want to reuse a project developed in vb.net in c# webform project. The login form should be same for both the projects. How can I achieve this? Can I add vb.net and C# forms in single project.
If created as separate projects in single solution, can I share the session variable between two projects?

I want a common login form for c# and vb.net project. Need to share user credentials between two apps

Comment: No, any project has exactly one language - if you need to mix, you need to have separate projects

Comment: As all future innovation is around C#/F#, https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2020/03/12/vb-in-net-5.aspx, you probably should convert all VB.NET code to C# and forget about "reuse" or "share" here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can intermix pages of vb and c# only if the web site is NOT a web site application.

So, it kind of depends.

If your web site is setup as a website application? Then no, you can't do this.

You can certainly take any of the code modules, classes, and business logic from the vb.net applcation, and refreence such assemblies in the new c# project.

And its not really recommended to do this anyway (ie: mix both types of pages in one project - but, you can do this for a web site, but not for web site applications).

I see VERY but VERY little advantage to simple re-writing all that code. It not like your going to get more features, or anything of value here.

If you looking to migrate to .net core, MVC etc? Then again, those pages could not be used anyway - even if they were written in C#.

So, either you consider this a migration project out of webforms (and .net 4.8), or you don't. Anything in-between is really a waste of time and resouces. If that site is to continue running as webforms, then I can't really make the case to migrate the code to c# - I just don't see any benefits here.

So, this can work for a asp.net web site, but not for a asp.net website "application".

And, I always hands down preferred the "application" choice, since then things like including other projects and code (often written in c#) can be used and is supported.

But, a page with code behind in vb.net, mixed in with pages and code behind in c#? No, you can't do this with a web site application, and giving up the application choice (vs that of a web site) I think is too high of a price to pay in that you lose out of the benefits of a asp.net application choice in the first place.

This sounds like good money after bad. Unless you going to migrate to a newer framework? It makes VERY little sense to spend time + money to migrate to JUST c#, and I can't see any real benefits of doing so.

if the developers in question know well asp.net + webforms, then the learning curve to maintain the site "as is" with vb.net? I can't see more then a day or so for any good c# developer to get up to speed with vb.net.

c# or vb.net is really moot - what matters is a good solid skill set in the .net framework, and unless you jumping over to .net core, then as noted, I can't see how the cost of this work can be justified. it in effect amounts to stealing money from those paying for this conversion, and that means someone is being mislead, or miss informed here.